# How to get selected value in select tag in rails edit view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I'm creating a select field with `<%= f.select :gender, [['Male', 1], ['Female', 2]] %>` for my rails app and using this piece of code to accomplish that. The problem is - when I select a value and set it, in the `edit` view I get `Male` even if the user has selected `Female` and this setting has been saved to database.

What do I have to do to make the selected value show up in the edit view as well?

Comment: What's the value being saved in `gender` column? Can you also post the controller and model code where you save this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using SimpleForm or standard Rails form_for. You should set "selected" option like this:

```
<%= f.select :gender, [['Male', 1], ['Female', 2]], selected: f.object.gender %>
```

If you want to setup also default value, go for "default" option.